# Colorcells and Rowcolor in spreadtab

Tags: tables, color, spreadtab

I wonder how to add some colorcell, rowcolor and so on in this type of table

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
  \usepackage{spreadtab}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
  \hline
  & @Ammount&   @Buy & @ Sell & @Profit & \\ \hline
  &  & 1& 3 &                           & \\  \hline
  &  &  & 2 &                           & \\ \hline
  \hline
  &  &  & :={ sum(d2:d3) } &            & \\
  \hline
  \end{spreadtab}
   
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to customize styles of tables while using `spreadtab` if you would like to use `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tblr}{colspec={|c|c|c|c|c|c|},row{1}={blue9},cell{4}{4}={red8}}}
\hline
& @Ammount&   @Buy & @ Sell & @Profit & \\ \hline
&  & 1& 3 &                           & \\  \hline
&  &  & 2 &                           & \\ \hline
\hline
&  &  & :={ sum(d2:d3) } &            & \\
\hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, thank You so much!